# Does Google crawl and index sites hosted on an IP address only (with no domain name) and non-standard port?

Tags: google-search-console

I have website on `203.162.177.159:8071` (Actually, that isn't the real IP address, I changed it for this question.)  Because of an internal rule, this site must not have a domain name, and running on **non-standard port**.

In Google Webmaster Tools, I see

- no crawl errors found
- no verification errors found
- I tried "Fetch as Google" and they are all successful.  I can then click the URL to get to the page myself.
- I don't have the sitemap yet

So why the crawled page and indexed page is still **zero**? Does Google not accept non-domain-name URLs?

Comment: Do you have a robots.txt? How long is your site online / added to GWT?

Comment: @LockeVN You're using a non-standard port, so you might add that to your question as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how these would be shown in Webmaster Tools, so maybe that's a bit confusing (send me an example via Google+ if you want me to check with the team).

Answer (score 5):

Google *does* index sites accessible under IPs.
Random example: [162.13.35.10](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:162.13.35.10)

Also indirectly confirmed by Matt Cutts:
[Can rel="canonical" index my hostname and not my IP address?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vw0tmgZsjok)

Comment: Yep, we can index sites on IP addresses and/or on non-standard ports.