# Does Google treat different ports as different sites?

Tags: google, duplicate-content, search-engine-indexing, azure, port-number

I host my website on Azure and I have recently activated a feature to make it possible for me to directly access each server instance in our web farm by a port number. For example `http://example.com:10015` and `http://example.com:10016`.

I'm a bit nervous of duplicated content in Google and I do not want Google to detect these URLs in some way and start to index them. I recently had this problem with Azure's default `cloudapp.net` domains and I have now both added a 301 for this domain and also a *robots.txt* rewrite so I disallow bots for this domain.

I wanted to use a *robots.txt* rewrite rule for the *different port*s as well but it doesn't seems to work for some reason. I don't know if it has to do with Azure's handling, but for example the `SERVER_PORT` variable is returning port `80` even if I go the to port `10015`.

Anyhow, I was just trying to add my site with a port specification in Google Webmaster Tools, but that didn't work. So basically my question is if I have to worry about this at all, does Google even treat different ports as different sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Does Google even treat different ports as different sites?*

Yes. Google can and does index URLs with non-standard ports, as relayed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wO-1zvXgzg) by Google's Matt Cutts, and also confirmed in a comment to this answer [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61762/does-google-crawl-and-index-sites-hosted-on-an-ip-address-only-with-no-domain-n/61767#61767) on our site by Google's John Mueller: `Yep, we can index sites on IP addresses and/or on non-standard ports`.

> *I'm a bit nervous of duplicated content in Google*

If these different URLs return the same content, then you can indicate to Google which is the [preferred URL for your content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) to index by using a [canonical link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en#2). As indicated there by Google:

`To address these issues, we recommend you define a canonical URL for content (or equivalent content) available through multiple URLs.`

Comment: Thanks! I have canonicals for my https mirror I just remembered so I guess I will just use the same.