# Does Google treat websites with different port as different website?

Tags: seo, google

I've seen similar question on stackexchange,

[Does Google treat different ports as different sites?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77378/does-google-treat-different-ports-as-different-sites)

However, the answer does not provide whether how Google treats different port website as different website (such as subdomain)

so to summarize, does Google treat below sites as different as subdomain? or identical as subdirectory?

`https://example.com` vs. `https://example.com:####`

Comment: I think the post you have mentioned answers your question. Yes, Google treats different ports as different sites.

Comment: Google doesn't usually treat subdomains as completely different sites.   See [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)