# Does a website require a domain name (.com, .org etc) or can an I.P. address be registered on its own?

Tags: domain-registration, ip-address

I'd like for my website to not have a domain name, and only use the IP address. However, when I go to register a website, the service provider demands a domain name. How would I go about registering an IP address without a corresponding domain name?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Google crawl and index sites hosted on an IP address only (with no domain name) and non-standard port?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61762/does-google-crawl-and-index-sites-hosted-on-an-ip-address-only-with-no-domain-n)

Comment: @AndrewLott OP question is not related to crawling and indexing, so I don't think it is duplicated question.

Comment: Where else would you "register a website"?

Comment: For the second part of your question, if you ever did want to register control of an IP address you would start by [choosing a region on the IANA website](http://www.iana.org/numbers) and applying at the relevant Registry (for a block of addresses). This would cost quite a bit and requires a high level of technical proficiency, but it is possible. For shared hosting of a website you would never have to worry about this though, because the hosting company has already done this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a domain name to access a website. You just need a web server with a static IP and every time you want to access that server you should remember that number. That is what the domain name mainly does, translating those sequences of numbers into a readable, easy to memorize name.

To put it easy, you don't register an IP address, you use the IP address that a web server has.

So, don't register a domain name, just use some type of [web hosting service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_hosting_service) and note down its IP address.

I would like to point out also that in case of a shared server or if using subdomains, you would need to have a domain to help the server locate your desired website, the above answer applies to a dedicated server or if the IP resolves directly to that website, that is, it has just one website.

Comment: This perfectly answered my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: On shared hosting, if you visit the IP address you will hit the host's server page.  Assuming your host has it enabled, to visit your specific site you would visit something like 123.456.789.012/~yoursite

And while Marcanuy is right, you don't need a domain to access a website, you might need a domain to create an account.  Doesn't mean you have to use it.